# Error assigning variable in scheduled task action

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a .xml file containing a username and encrypted password (the accessid and key for an API). Using the following line, I retrieve the credential:

```
$Credential = Import-CliXml -Path "${env:\userprofile}\token.xml"
```

This works great in the shell, but I need to schedule this command (along with the script that uses the cred). In the scheduled task, I am starting powershell.exe and passing the following as an argument:

```
-Command "& $credential = Import-CliXml -Path ${env:\userprofile}\token.Cred"
```

But I get back the error:

```
& : The term 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential' is not recognized
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & System.Management.Automation.PSCredential = Import-CliXml -Path C:\ ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.Manageme...on.PSCredential:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried several variations, including:

```
-Command (& $credential = Import-CliXml -Path ${env:\userprofile}\token.Cred)
-Command ($credential = Import-CliXml -Path ${env:\userprofile}\token.Cred)
-Command "$credential = Import-CliXml -Path ${env:\userprofile}\token.Cred"
```

But I get the same error. I need the variable, because I am going to also run the following (in the same action):

```
.\script.ps1 -AccessId $Credential.UserName -AccessKey ((System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal::PtrToStringAuto(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal::SecureStringToBSTR($Credential.Password))))
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

```
# using cmd.exe
powershell.exe -Command "& {$credential = Import-CliXml -Path ${env:\userprofile}\token.Cred}"
# using powershell, escape special characters
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-Command `"& {`$credential = Import-CliXml -Path `${env:\userprofile}\token.Cred;pause}`""
```

Comment: `= : The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+ & { = Import-CliXml -Path C:\Users\srvc_tools_app\token.Cred}
+     ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (=:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException` Seems to not like having a variable assigned inside the script block.

Comment: Are you calling this from a script or tried running it from a command line (cmd.exe/powershell.exe)?

Comment: It will be in a scheduled task, but at the moment, I am running it from a PS session.